# Option value in ISML

Tags: html, isml

I have a dropdown list (values populated from an object) from which the value selected goes on to the next page. However if that value is selected then another property of that object should go on to the next page.

My current code is:

```
<select name="ElementName" class="dropdown"
                            id="ElementsDropDownList">
                            <isloop iterator="ELEMENTS">
                                <option value="#ELEMENTS:ElementName#"><isprint
                                    value="#ELEMENTS:ElementLabel#">
                                </option>
                            </isloop>
                        </select>
```

I want something like :

```
<select name="ElementName" class="dropdown"
                            id="ElementsDropDownList">
                            <isloop iterator="ELEMENTS">
                                <option value="#ELEMENTS:ElementName#"><isprint
                                    value="#ELEMENTS:ElementLabel#">
                                </option>

<input type="Hidden" name="extraField" id="extraFieldUUID" value="<isprint
                                    value="#ELEMENTS:ElementValue#">">
                            </isloop>
                        </select>
```

Here input field inside the loop is not working.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid HTML.  Are you using some other technology that you're not telling us?

Comment: He is using the system intershop - researched the tag isloop https://support.intershop.com/static/ISML-Tag---ISLOOP.html

Comment: yes it is intershop...

Comment: I added in my edit on your question the word Intershop in the headline. You need to know that the code above isn't a real html - it only looks like html because html is still xml. I don't know if there will be a lot support for this on stackoverflow even the tag doesn't exist so try your luck on : https://support.intershop.com/sws/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `input` element *inside* of a `select` element.  It would have to be separate:

```
<select name="ElementName" class="dropdown" id="ElementsDropDownList">
  <isloop iterator="ELEMENTS">
    <option value="#ELEMENTS:ElementName#">
      <isprint value="#ELEMENTS:ElementLabel#">
    </option>
  </isloop>
</select>
<input type="Hidden" name="extraField" id="extraFieldUUID" value="<isprint value="#ELEMENTS:ElementValue#">">
```

*However*, clearly this won't work in your case because this is outside the loop.  You'd need another loop, which means *every* `ElementValue` value would be included in the form.  That's... no good.

It sounds like what you're trying to achieve is to have a `select` with *two* values.  It doesn't really do that, pretty much by design.  I can think of two options at the moment:

1. Include a hidden `input` outside the `select` element as shown above, but don't set a value for it.  Include the list of possible values in JavaScript (as a hash table of some sort, most likely, using the `ElementName` as the key).  Then attach an event handler to the `select` element's `change` event which sets the hidden `input` value based on the newly selected value.
2. *Or*, include both values in the `select` as delimited strings and parse them back out to separate values on the receiving page.  Maybe something like:

(I'm completely guessing on the syntax, since I don't know anything about the templating tool you're using.)  Then the code on the receiving page would receive some delimited string, something like:

```
"SomeElement|123"
```

That code would then need to parse that string into its two component values.

Comment: Thanks for your help David . 2nd option will not work as I have to display only one value . the first option will also not work as I cannot include a list of possible values in Javascript as the values are added during run time.

Comment: @user3033031: Well, both options require code of some sort.  If the technology you're using doesn't have any ability to parse strings or to emit JavaScript (or any non-HTML markup) to the page then you're somewhat out of luck.  At that point the technology you're using doesn't fit the design you have.  `select` elements simply don't have more than one posted value.  No form element does.